# IAP product name display language

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My question:

If my  iTunes Connect  user account is English, and the device language set to be Chinese. How to display the IAP product  title and description to be Chinese? I want to display product title and description according to the Iphone [Language & Region] setting.

I found the information from here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-LOCALIZATION-MY_IN_APP_PURCHASE_HAS_LOCALIZED_INFORMATION_FOR_VARIOUS_LANGUAGES_ON_ITUNES_CONNECT__HOWEVER__THE_LOCALIZEDDESCRIPTION_AND_LOCALIZEDTITLE_PROPERTIES_ALWAYS_RETURN_INFORMATION_IN_ENGLISH_EVEN_THOUGH_MY_TEST_DEVICE_LANGUAGE_IS_NOT_SET_TO_ENGLISH

My In-App Purchase has localized information for various languages on iTunes Connect. However, the localizedDescription and localizedTitle properties always return information in English even though my test device language is not set to English
localizedDescription and localizedTitle return localized information whose language is based on the current iTunes Store rather than the current device language setting. For instance, if your in-app purchase is localized for German in iTunes Connect and you are logged with an English test user account, then localizedDescription and localizedTitle will return information localized in English. To have localizedDescription and localizedTitle return information localized in German, login with a German test user account on your test device.

[image]

Comment: Have you localized your application? I mean strings in the application

Comment: yes，i have both chinese and English. And the product price is showing correctly in HKD